# Book in two languages (left pages in one language and right pages in a second language)

Tags: languages, books, layout, page

I have a book `\documentclass[11pt]{book}` and I would like to write it in two languages (english and german).

My idea would be to repeat each page of the book in both languages, in such a way that all the left pages of the book are in one language (english) and all the right pages of the book are in the second language (german). Indeed, once you open a book, you have always pages on the left, and pages on the right :-)

In other words, I would like to have the same structure/layout of my book repeated on the left and right pages of my book, i.e. each left page with the same structure/layout of the corresponding right page, but just with different languages (left pages in english and right pages in german).

**Any ideas on how to achieve it in Latex?**

Comment: There are special packages for parallel text, the most well-known is [reledpar](https://ctan.org/pkg/reledpar).

Comment: thanks a lot @Marjin !

Comment: @Marijn - reledpar?  Never heard of it.  Is it anything like paracol?  ;-)

Comment: I use the [parcolumns](https://ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns?lang=en) package for my triplicate typesetting (German/English/English) of Wittgenstein's [Tractatus](https://people.umass.edu/klement/tlp/); if I had to do it over I might consider some of the alternatives, but it worked decently well for my needs.

Comment: @JohnKormylo `reledpar` is a generally installed LaTeX package. Try reading the manual (via `texdoc reledpar` for example).

Comment: @PeterWilson I think John was making a joke, because I said `reledpar` was the most famous... indeed `paracol` would be a good alternative as well. Here on the site there are slightly more questions [tagged paracol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paracol) (133) compared to questions [tagged reledpar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reledpar) (119) so maybe my statement was not fully accurate.